# How to integrate lib into python project using docker?

Tags: python, docker

I rewrote some sync python lib to async. How do I integrate it into my project?

I did the following:

1. `clone` it from github and rewrited
2. build the lib using `python3 setup.py bdist_wheel --universal` and
   got the file `.whl` file

How can I integrate it to my project?
Currently I have the following docker file:

```
FROM python:3.6

MAINTAINER ...

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . $APP_DIR

EXPOSE 8080
CMD python app.py
```

How do I copy the `.whl` file into to container and install it using `pip3 install {...}.whl`?

Answer (score 2):

First add `WORKDIR /app` before `COPY requirements.txt` to specify your app working directory inside the container, then if you have xxx.whl in the same folder as `requirements.txt` just copy it `COPY xxx.whl /app` then `RUN pip install xxx.whl`

like this:

```
FROM python:3.6

MAINTAINER ...

# specify workdir
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app
# copy xxx.whl from host to container
COPY xxx.whl /app
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
# install xxx.whl
RUN pip install xxx.whl
COPY . /app

EXPOSE 8080
CMD python app.py
```